# XML Android layout problems

Tags: android, xml, layout, gravity, layout-gravity

So I am having problems with some XML layout coding... I am supposed to replicate this image

[image: http://s28.postimg.org/n257m4dil/Untitled.png]

but so far I seem to be only able to get this far and the checkout button refuses to stay to the right even when I do use android:gravity="right" to float right within its container... :/

[image: http://s29.postimg.org/bqzspid13/pic3.png]

This is the code I have so far:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".CartActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
   >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="Shopping Cart"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
         >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Subtotal:" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#800000"
            android:text="£???" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/checkout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Checkout" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did you solved the issue?

Comment: Thank you very much, the issue is solved :) 

However I did not need android:weightSum="3", using it actually made it go all over the place. However putting in android:layout_weight="1" into the two text views solved the problem and thus the checkout button did not need realigning :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a `android:weightSum="3"` for your inner

Layout with the three elements, and after that,

`android:layout_weight="1"` to each view

this will make the views to hold 1/3 of the available space

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:weightSum="3"
     >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Subtotal:" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#800000"
        android:text="£???"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/checkout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Checkout" 
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT  fill_parent is deprecated use match_parent**

Comment: The best will be if your android:layout_width="0dp". Also, you can make android:weightSume="100"(3 will be good too) and make child not equal eg. 20(0,5), 20(0,5), 60(2).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a Relativelayout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Subtotal:" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#800000"
        android:text="£???" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/checkout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Checkout" >
    </Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```